# JButtons on GridLayout - MineSweeper

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm writing MineSweeper and using `JButton`s on a `GridLayout`. The numbers of rows and columns are entered by the user, so setting fixed size may cause several problems.

How can I remove the space between the buttons without setting the fixed size of the panel?

[image: Adjustable cell MineSweeper]

Comment: It is better to use GridbagLayout, this will give you all the options you need for customizing your UI, like setting weight etc.

Comment: 1) Generally it is achieved using a `GridLayout` with no spacing and `pack()` on the frame.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be more of a issue with `JButton` then with `GridLayout`

Here, I replaced `JButton` with `JPanel` (and some border magic)

[image]

The other thing I tried was passing a negative h/vgap to the `GridLayout`

[image]

I'd however not recommend this, as it may have unforeseen effects on other platforms.

I personally, would be tempted to use a custom `JLabel` (with it's own mouse listener attached) to take the place of the buttons.  You could even fire and action event when it's clicked...

Comment: *"This seems to be more of a issue with JButton"*  I don't think so.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) shows how to use 4 icons as buttons (5 as labels). in a UI with no spaces between them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The buttons as there are, have there border offset, so that there is space between the outer edge and the default border, so the white space between the buttons is actually internal spacing. Take the border out and you can probably solve the white space issue - at least in my testing

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the hgap and vgap to 0 when creating the gridlayout instance.

Like,

```
   GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(0,2,0,0);
```

Comment: `new GridLayout(0,2);` would have the same result.  `0` is the default. ;)