# How to paint on a Jpanel?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

i am trying to add 2 different panels in a Frame. one panel adds few buttons in the frame. others frame will add a chess board into the frame. i am confused, how to draw this board on a panel. my Frame will have a board on the top and buttons at the bottom. Moreover, let me know if i am somewhere wrong in the given code can anybody help me? my Code is

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    private JFrame main;
    private JPanel board;
    private JPanel buttons;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton delete;

    public Test()
    {
        main=new JFrame();
        board=new JPanel();
        buttons=new JPanel();
        add=new JButton("Add");
        delete=new JButton("Delete");
        init();
        addButtons();
    }
    public void init()
    {
        main.setSize(700,700);
        main.setVisible(true);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(main.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void addButtons()
    {
        buttons.setSize(700,40);
        buttons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttons.add(add);
        buttons.add(delete);
        main.add(buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }
    public void addBoxes()
    {
        // what should be my code here...??
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Test();

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? What doesn't work about this?

Comment: i dont know to paint chess board on my Jpane board and add it in my frame

Comment: have a look into http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game1.html for info on how to use JPanels.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2562685/230513) and [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563350/230513).

Comment: There are. Any ways to  achieve this, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891250/creating-a-multicolored-board/15891779#15891779), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870608/creating-a-draw-rectangle-filled-with-black-color-function-in-java-for-a-grid/15870637#15870637), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448535/jbuttons-on-gridlayout-minesweeper/13448715#13448715)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need a component to paint on, like a `JPanel`.
2. You need to @Override its `paintComponent` method
3. You can use a loop to paint using `Graphics` context
4. Use a flag to alternate between colors.

Take a look at some [Painting Graphics tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

In the mean time, give this a whirl

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final int DIM_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int DIM_HEIGHT = 640;
    private static final int SQ_SIZE = 80;

    boolean black = true;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM_HEIGHT; i += SQ_SIZE) {
            if (black) {
                black = false;
            } else {
                black = true;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM_WIDTH; j += SQ_SIZE) {
                if (black) {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.fillRect(j, i, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE);
                    black = false;
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g.fillRect(j, i, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE);
                    black = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Board());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DIM_WIDTH, DIM_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What if i had to add a another panel with two buttons in it just under my chess board?

Comment: Take out the `main` method and the `createAndshowGui` method. Then the class is just a regular panel. You can add if the a `JFrame` of your own class. Then just add a separate panel below it, with the buttons.

Comment: This could also be achieved with the use of GridLayout and JPanel, which would reduce the complexity of the management and make  it easier to place pieces on the board for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886200/sudoku-board-using-jpanels-in-java/12888426#12888426)

Comment: can u please explain what does these statements do?? frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();

Comment: `.pack()` just maintains the preferred sizes of the components in the frame, to a minimal size, and `.setLocationbyPlatform()` just sets the location of the frame. You can also set it to `null` to center it. Also you may want to look at @MadProgrammer link. His idea seems more reasonable.